# Cannot determine the P-value

Tags: self-study, chi-squared-test, p-value

I have a chi squared of 0.1185 with 1 degree of freedom.  How can i determine the P-value?

Comment: Because $\chi^2(1)$ is the distribution of the square of a standard normal variate, your question is tantamount to asking for the probability that a standard normal value exceeds $\sqrt{0.1185}\approx0.34$ in size.  That's an elementary calculation (and I'm sure you have software or accurate tables to carry it out).

Answer (score 5):

By p-value I presume you mean "the probability of seeing a value of my test statistic as large as this, if it really comes from a $\chi^2$ distribution with one degree of freedom".  So if you get a low p-value it means it is an improbable value to have seen.

In R:

```
1-pchisq(0.1185, 1)
```

or

```
pchisq(0.1185, 1, lower=FALSE)
```

In Excel

```
=1-CHISQ.DIST(0.1185,1, TRUE)
```

or

```
=CHISQ.DIST.RT(A2,1)
```

The p-value is very large because your value of the test statistic is actually considerably less than the average value of such a $\chi^2$ random variable.  If anything, it is unusually *small*. So basically, you do not have a large value and hence there is not evidence to dismiss the hypothesis that it genuinely comes from a $\chi^2$ distribution.

Comment: so, what is the p-value?

Comment: I would recommend you always use `FALSE` instead of `F`, so it should be `pchisq(0.1185, 1, lower = FALSE)`.

Comment: @user176105 I'll leave it up to you to calculate... you must have access to either R or Excel, surely.

Comment: @PeterEllis so my teacher just gave me a table like this: http://www.sociology.ohio-state.edu/people/ptv/publications/p%20values/t_table.jpg so the only thing i can do is narrow my p-value to a range?

Comment: Linear interpolation of the 2-tailed p-value for $z=\sqrt{0.1185}$ gives $0.73$ which is fully accurate to two d.p.  (In R this can be done as `(sqrt(0.1185)-.39)/(.25-.39) * (.80-.70) + 0.70`; the numbers 0.39, 0.25, 0.80, and 0.70 come from your teacher's table.)  Alternatively, applying Simpson's Rule (`x<-0.1185;1 - sqrt(x)*(2*exp(-x/2) + 4)/(3*sqrt(2*pi))`) gives 0.7306, which is within 0.0001 of the truth: no table is needed at all.

Comment: @Henrik - thanks - have changed F to FALSE in the R code.  I take your point in the comments below that this might avoid confusion at some point.

Answer (score 1):

The upper tail of the $\chi^2_1$ distribution, beyond 0.1185 is

```
pchisq(0.1185, df=1, lower=F)
[1] 0.7306671
```

That's your p-value

Comment: How did you get that exact number?  my teacher gave me a chart and I could tell my value was between 0.7 and 0.9, but I couldn't get any more accurate

Comment: @Henrik Why use FALSE instead of F? F seems to work

Comment: @guest was using R.

Comment: @Peter - I think this should have been a comment, but the answer to your question is that TRUE and FALSE are reserved words, but T and F are not. So you can do things like `F <- TRUE`. This obviously has unintended consequences for the poor soul who inherits your code.

Comment: guest, when questions have the "homework" tab, we try not to give the actual answer, just hints--just for future reference.

Comment: In fairness to @guest, the homework tab didn't appear till after s/he'd answered the question

Comment: @PeterFlom Because only `TRUE` and `FALSE` are reserved keywords (see `?reserved`). `F` and `T` are just variables assigned to your convenience. So you can easily use the following construction to produce horrible things: `T <- FALSE; F <- TRUE`.

Comment: Ah ha. That makes sense.